# Magnific Popup: error trying to invoke a YouTube iframe popup from an inline popup

Tags: javascript, magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup to show an inline modal with an image and some text. The client now wants to add a link **inside** this inline modal to watch a video - with this video being inside a new modal popup.

We are using the video modal throughout the site already without any problems, however when the link is inside the inline modal the black overlay stays, the inline modal goes away as expected, but no video modal appears.

```
<a class="modal-youtube" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5r15IUNWhl8">Watch a Video</a>
```

In the console it has this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5r15IUNWhl8
```

For reference, here's my javascript code - it's all pretty standard stuff from the docs, though.

```
$('.modal-youtube, .modal-vimeo, .modal-gmaps').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 700,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,

    fixedContentPos: false
});



$('.modal').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        showCloseBtn: true
  });
```

It sounds like Magnific Popup is having trouble rebuilding the YouTube link to create the iframe, but I have no idea why it works everywhere else except for inside a modal window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm brand new to magnific-popup, and I'm experiencing the same issue: my youtube `src` doesn't build correctly. I'm not launching the popup through an `<a>` tag, but rather on a `<div>`.  I may not be addressing your situation, but here's my workaround idea for you. I'm not crazy about it, but it worked.

```
// store the youtube url in a data- attribute as I build my page
$(section_item).data("yt",thisLink);

//section_item is my <div> where the magnific-popup spawns from
 $(section_item).magnificPopup({
      items:{
           src:$(section_item).data("yt")
      },
      type:'iframe',
      callbacks:{
           open:function({
                $("iframe").attr("src",$.magnificPopup.instance.currItem.src);
           }
      },
});
```

I was seeing a broken youtube `src`:

```
file://www.youtube.com/embed/ttps://www.youtube.com/embed/-fuulLKmxxg?autoplay=1
```

The `open` callback is where I forced the `src` to be corrected, where it's chopped down, recalling it from `currItem.src`:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/-fuulLKmxxg
```

I tried playing with the `patterns` object, in the [documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#iframe-type), but I couldn't get that to work.  Hope this was a little helpful.

Comment: From what I can tell, mixing and matching modal types is what's causing the issue. I ended up having to stay with the same modal type as my first popup and do a regular embed:

`<iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Just make sure you turn off auto play or that sucker will start making noise before you ever view it :)

Comment: That's a good tip to disable autoplay, thanks. I had it off and was thinking of turning it on.  Now I won't.

Comment: Safari won't start playing it till the modal pops up, but I think Firefox and Chrome did.